# Memory leak Valgrind doesn't report but code using so much memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, ram

I have posted recently about a segmentation fault issue that I have been getting in my code when running with Valgrind, I have got rid of the segmentation fault problem however, now the code is running, but is "eating" so much memory which indicates a memory leak somewhere that valgrind doesn't necessarily see? I am not sure really. For example it would run to the 40th iteration before the kernel kills my process.

[previous post: Segmentation Fault with Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64346021/used-uninitialized-value-of-size-8-by-strcat-using-c-with-valgrind-while-savin)

If I run the code with the corrections to the code: (initializing my arrays and changes size of arrays to be large enough)

```
char save [16] = {0};
snprintf(save, 16,  "%d", saveNum);
const char *type = " .txt";
            
char Nfilename[16] = {0};
strcat(Nfilename, "N");
strcat(Nfilename, save);

char KEfilename[16] = {0};
strcat(KEfilename, "KE");
strcat(KEfilename, save);

char KIfilename[16] = {0};
strcat(KIfilename, "KI");
strcat(KIfilename, save);

char Pfilename[16] = {0};
strcat(Pfilename, "P");
strcat(Pfilename, save);

print2DArrf(Nfilename, N); 
print2DArrf(KEfilename, KE);
print2DArrf(KIfilename, KI);
print2DArrf(Pfilename, P);
```

This has fixed the segmentation fault issue I was having at the exact iteration every single time. However, if I run the code for few iterations my computer would run out of RAM, I tried running the code with the activity memory monitor on Mac (since Valgrind takes days to run on debugging mode and give no memory leak issues) and the result is the code reaches to 16GB within few minutes!! I made sure to free everything, so something else must be happening.

I am wondering what's going on, and why is it taking so much memory in the code and how to fix it? I thought looking at each one of the major functions (shown below) in my code and run each one separately to pinpoint the issue but that seems tedious and might not really help. Is it actually a memory leak?

These are the major functions that I was looking to run individually to tackle this "memory" issue:

```
// calculate some values 
        convolution(Nk, KEk, Pek);
        Fourier3D(Pek, kb, Pek);

        
        convolution(Nk, KIk, Pik);
        Fourier3D(Pik, kb, Pik);
        
        Freqk(Nk, KIk,KEk , kb, eps0, mi, me, ri, rn, nn, Oci, Oce, e, nuink, nuiek, nuiik, nuenk, nueek, nueik, isigPk, NNk);
        
        dk(Nk, kx, dndxk);
        dk(Nk, ky, dndyk);

        calcPSk(dndxk, dndyk, Pik, Pek, nuink, nuiek, nuenk, nueik, isigPk, Oci, Oce, u, B, ksqu, potSourcek);
```

Example of the main code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Functions.h"
#include "fftw3.h"
#include <cstring>

int main(){         
    
    // Setting parameters 
    double frequency = 200.0;    
    double dt = 0.1;        
    double tend = 5000.; 
    double err_max = 1e-7;          

    int P_iter_max = 500;      

    int iter_max = tend / dt;
    int saveNumber = 1;

//Initialize Parameters 

double *N;
    N = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));

fftw_complex *Nk;
    Nk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk*sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

double *KIk;
    KIk = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));

double *KE;
    KE = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));
    
fftw_complex *KEk;
    KEk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    
    
double *P;
    P = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));
    
    fftw_complex *Pk;
    Pk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

//Save I.Cs 

    int P_iter = Potk(invnk, dndxk, dndyk, Pk, PSk, kx, ky, ninvksq, err_max, P_iter_max);



    for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_max; iter++){

         // calculate some values 
        convolution(Nk, KEk, Pek);
        Fourier3D(Pek, kb, Pek);

        
        convolution(Nk, KIk, Pik);
        Fourier3D(Pik, kb, Pik);
        
        Freqk(Nk, KIk,KEk , kb, eps0, mi, me, ri, rn, nn, Oci, Oce, e, nuink, nuiek, nuiik, nuenk, nueek, nueik, isigPk, NNk);
        
        dk(Nk, kx, dndxk);
        dk(Nk, ky, dndyk);

        calcPSk(dndxk, dndyk, Pik, Pek, nuink, nuiek, nuenk, nueik, isigPk, Oci, Oce, u, B, ksqu, potSourcek);
    



         //Check for convergence

         // Save I.C loop

        P_iter = Pk(NNk, dndxk, dndyk, phik, potSourcek, kx, ky, ninvksqu, err_max, P_iter_max);
    } // seems to be the correct location of for loop end (see comment)
    double time[iter_max + 1];
    time[0] = 0;
    
    c2rfft(Nk, N);
    c2rfft(KEk, KE);    
    c2rfft(KIk, KI);
    c2rfft(Pk, P);
    
    char Ninitial[] = "N_initial.txt";
    char KEinitial[] = "KE_initial.txt";
    char KIinitial[] = "KI_initial.txt";
    char Pinitial[] = "P_initial.txt";
    

    print2DArrf(Ninitial, N);
    print2DArrf(KEinitial, KE);
    print2DArrf(KIinitial, KI);
    print2DArrf(Pinitial, P);
} // close of main() (??)
```

I Would really appreciate some insight on how to tackle this problem. I am new to this and I am finding some difficulty understanding the issue.

Comment: your main code is not complete, where is the end `}` of the for loop, post a "compiling" version of main , which of the non displayed functions do malloc stuff.

Comment: Yeah sorry this main code was just an example, so for loop ends after P_iter, and malloc is done by fftw library. I am not sure how to post a full compiling version for you here. I am new to the website.

Comment: So I just tried running it for the first function only and it's still giving me the same issue.  I see a surge in the memory in my memory activity monitor. I don't know how else to tackle this maybe run it with Valgrind again for each function.

Comment: what is the function of `time[]`? Where are the variables `Pek`, `kb`, `Pik`, `eps0,mi, me, ri, rn, nn, Oci, Oce, e, nuink, nuiek, nuiik, nuenk, nueek, nueik, isigPk, NNk` and a lot more. You can only have a memory leak if some function inside the for loop allocates memory, So which function allocates memory?

Comment: if convolution only is causing a memory leak than look at the source code of convolution or read the doc of convolution

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the whole for loop to see if it is the calls to fftw_malloc that cause the problem or not. Also just how big are nx, ny etc?

Comment: Okay so I tried only running the convolution function with valgrind and is giving me an initializing error: ``Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`` and ``==2722== Use of uninitialised value of size 8`` which makes sense. Since, originally I was having a segmentation fault due to not initializing some of my arrays correctly and not setting them to be large enough. So, I assume this is setting off errors for all the other un-initialized arrays, but there are so many of those I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Hard code the loop to do just a single iteration and then run again under Valgrind. Then look for your leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you free() all malloc'ed memory from heap

```
double *N;
    N = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));

fftw_complex *Nk;
    Nk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk*sizeof(fftw_complex)); 

double *KIk;
    KIk = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));

double *KE;
    KE = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));
    
fftw_complex *KEk;
    KEk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 
    
    
double *P;
    P = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny*sizeof(double));
    
    fftw_complex *Pk;
    Pk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(nx*nyk* sizeof(fftw_complex)); 


    .
    .
    .
    free(N);
    free(Nk);
    free(KIk);
    free(KE);
    free(KEk);
    free(P);
    free(Pk);
```

Comment: these mallocs are outside the loop so no cause of memory leak

Comment: I have freed everything just in case so I don't think it's causing the memory leak unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

By `valgrind`, I assume that you’re referring to using the `memcheck` tool. `memcheck` only considers something a leak if you don’t free it at the end of execution.

Without knowing the details of the convolution and Fourier transforms, you can analyze the memory usage of your program using thé `massif` tool of `valgrind`. You can get a series of snapshots and see where your out-of-control memory is coming from.